# arduino format and SD Card with an esp32 as fat32 that is connected as an SDMMC host

Tags: arduino-esp32, fat32, sdmmc

I am trying to format an SD card with an ESP32 connected to an SD card as a SDMMC host. I would like to figure out how to format it as FAT32 within the Arduino framework. Does anyone know if this is possible to do within the Arduino framework? I can create, read, write and delete files, but I cannot figure out how to format an SD Card.

I believe it's possible using Espressif's ESPIDF, but I cannot figue out how to get this working in Arduino. the following page describes the basics of working with an SD Card wired up as an SDMMC host:

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/sdmmc_host.html

This does not cover how to format an SD card wired up this way. I wish I could offer more details on this but I am a loss for where to start. Any and all help is appreciated.

Someone suggested that this might work in espidf:

```
#include "esp_vfs_fat.h"
#include "driver/sdmmc_host.h"
#include "sdmmc_cmd.h"
#include "SD.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize SDMMC host driver
  sdmmc_host_t host = SDMMC_HOST_DEFAULT();
  sdmmc_slot_config_t slot_config = SDMMC_SLOT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
  esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount_config_t mount_config = {
    .format_if_mount_failed = true,
    .max_files = 5,
    .allocation_unit_size = 16 * 1024
  };
  sdmmc_card_t* card;
  esp_err_t err = esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount("/sdcard", &host, &slot_config, &mount_config, &card);

  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Failed to mount SD card (%s)\n", esp_err_to_name(err));
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("SD card mounted successfully");

  // List files in root directory
  File root = SD.open("/");
  File file = root.openNextFile();
  while (file) {
    Serial.println(file.name());
    file = root.openNextFile();
  }
}

void loop() {
  
}
```